# How to browse packages in Unity?

Tags: unity

How to browse packages in Unity?

I have the `Version: 2020.1.17f1.4949 Personal`.

I want to install the Burst and Collection packages. I follow [this](https://forum.unity.com/threads/2d-animation-6-0-released-for-unity-2021-1.1107548/#post-7126691) guide. I open my **Package Manager** and try to search for `collections` and `burst`, but nothing pops up. Also, I see literally 0 packages and I can not understand why is it so hard to browse packages in Unity. I spent 2 hours, but was not able to find a single Unity package. That is very frustrating.

Could someone help me to figure out how the **Pacakge Manager** works, how could I browse packages?

[image]

It seems I was able to install the collections package by following [this](https://medium.com/@jeffreymlynch/where-are-the-missing-preview-packages-in-unity-2020-3ad0935e4193) guide. And I used the `com.unity.collections` as an URL, not as a name.

The trick was to be patient, because after the package is selected it took me ~2 minutes before the package actually started installing.

Now I am left to figure out how install the burst package.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

###### explanation

Packages starting in Unity 2020 are hidden by default in the Package Manager if they're in preview and are not close to their full release date. Now you have to either edit your project manifest file manually, or you can add the package from a git URL.

---

###### resources

- [This guide](https://medium.com/@jeffreymlynch/where-are-the-missing-preview-packages-in-unity-2020-3ad0935e4193) will explains things in more detail and with images.
- [Explanation](https://blog.unity.com/technology/package-manager-updates-in-unity-2020-1) of why Unity chose to start doing things this way.